comparing two cells and return the number till which character position both are both are same
I need to compare two cells and it has to tell till which position of character both cell values are same. See below example where both the columns are same till 34th Character.


@mayukh-bhattacharya can you please help here.

You could try using one of the following formulas:


• Option One:
=SUM(N(TOCOL(MID(B2,SEQUENCE(LEN(B2)),1)=MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1),2)))


• Option Two:
=FIND(TEXTSPLIT(B2,A2,,1),B2)-1


Thanks for the solutions!! Keep up your good work

Glad to know that. Thanks!

You can shorten this formula a bit, for example:
=SUM(N(LEFT(B2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)))=LEFT(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)))))

It is important to compare the same number of characters on both sides, then there will be no need to mask errors. You can take the length of any string, as long as it's the same.
In addition, comparing individual characters raises the risk of an incorrect result if one individual character is different and the next are the same, e.g.
Abcd25 and Abcx251.
